# Ajax loaded content referencing wrong node id in Drupal

Tags: php, jquery, drupal, view

I have a list of nodes each with a click. The click sends a node reference argument which loads a new view using ajax. Jquery collects the node reference number via a hidden input value on the content-type-tpl.php. Likewise the nodes in the new view each have a click which sends a node reference argument which loads a new view using ajax. However while the clicks in the original view work correctly, the clicks in the newly called view do not reference the correct node. Instead of referencing the node id for the node which is clicked, the node id of the next node in the view is collected instead. Oddly when placing `<?php echo $node->nid;?>` on the content-type-tpl.php, the correct node id is echoed on the page. But sadly this is not the one sent to the view argument. So clicking any node in the the newly loaded ajaxed view, sends the id for the next node. Here's the javacript:

```
Drupal.behaviors.ajaxlinks = function (context) {
    $('.morelink:not(.togg-processed)', context).addClass('togg-processed').each(function () {
      var myindex = $('.morelink').index($(this));
      var target = $('.newthing').eq(myindex)
      var nid = $(".mynid").eq(myindex).val();
    $(this).click(function() {
if (($('.hiddenrows').eq(myindex).is(":hidden")))
{    $('.hiddenrows').eq(myindex).show();
    $('.newthing').eq(myindex).show();
      var toLoad = Drupal.settings.basePath + 'replies/' + nid;
      xhr = $.ajax({
        url: toLoad,
        success: function(data) {
        $(target).html($(data));
     Drupal.attachBehaviors(context);
}
});
}
else
{
    $('.hiddenrows').eq(myindex).hide();
    $('.newthing').eq(myindex).hide();
}
    return false;
```

It's the same code so I can't see why it works differently in the newly loaded view. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? I suspect it's got something to with either the placement of or how I've declared my variables. Or perhaps it's got to do with a misuse of index , eq or this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Drupal.attachBehaviors should have fired on (target) instead of (context). It was refiring the script on the whole context instead of just the new ajaxed content. So I changed Drupal.attachBehaviors(context); to Drupal.attachBehaviors(target);

Now it works!